# Selection option in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-select, selection

I am working on a PHP quiz game and at the moment i am struggling a bit mixing php and html together as i have more previous experience in html. I have the following select option for quiz selection:

```
<select style="width: 300px" name="quizes" size="10">
  <option onClick="window.location = 'quiz1.php'" >Quiz 1</option>
  <option>Quiz 2</option>
  <option>Quiz 3</option>
  <option>Quiz 4</option>
  <option>Quiz 5</option>
</select>
```

I was told that this can be made with php code so that the new quizes are added onto it when created. Can somebody help me out with this, i dont quite understand how this would work.

I am not using database for my quizes, each quiz is/will be on one page, with the questions stored in array and the processing of the questions is on the same page.

Comment: So to understand correctly. In a directory you will for example 10 files quiz1.php, quiz2.php and so on. On the current page/landing page where the code posted above is from, will check for all files called quiz?.php and produce them as an option, to take the user to that particular page?

Comment: that is exactly right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It presumes that the page where the selection is made, is in the same directory as your quiz php pages.

```
<?php
$dir    = getcwd();
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $file)
{
    if (strpos($file,'quiz') !== false)
    {
        $fileName = ucfirst(str_replace('.php', '', $file));
        $quizPages[] = array('name'=>$fileName,'file'=>$file);
    } 
}
?>

<select style="width: 300px" name="quizes" size="10">
<?php
foreach($quizPages as $quiz)
{
    echo '<option name="' . $quiz["name"] . '" onClick="window.location = \'' . $quiz["file"] . '\'" >' . $quiz["name"] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```

Update for comment.

This is likely due to the fact you have a file called Quizes in that directory also, which having the word quiz in its being caught in the foreach loop. What I would suggest is to change this line

```
if (strpos($file,'quiz') !== false)
```

To this

```
if (strpos($file,'quiz') !== false && strpos($file,'quizes') === false)
```

Further update.
If you want to have a custom name for the quiz I would suggest you use the following naming convention quiz_desired_name.php. So for example If I have a quiz called what animal are you. Then the filename should be quiz_what_animal_are_you.php therefore separating words with underscores.

Then just replace this line

```
$fileName = ucfirst(str_replace('.php', '', $file));
```

with this

```
$fileName = ucfirst(str_replace(array('.php','quiz_','_'), array('','',' '), $file));
```

Comment: this is great, thank you so much. I just have one question, in the selection box now i have 2 quizes (quiz1 and quiz2) but there is also a third option named Quizes which doesn't do anything (when clicked). I do have quizes.php page however, this is where my selection box is located

Comment: i just figured it out as you posted the answer, i just simply changed the name of the php page to fix it. One more thing i would like to ask, it is not really important im just wondering if it possible to give each quiz a specific name in the selection box with this method?

Comment: @Omax no worries. If you end up going down the route of using a dropdown ie on selection rather than click, this link will help http://webdesign.about.com/od/javascript/f/blfaqddredirect.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this, added fire event in `<select>`

```
<select style="width: 300px" name="quizes" size="10" onChange="window.location = 'quiz1.php?val='+this.value;">
  <option value='Quiz 1'>Quiz 1</option>
  <option value='Quiz 2'>Quiz 2</option>
  <option  value='Quiz 3' >Quiz 3</option>
  <option  value='Quiz 4'>Quiz 4</option>
  <option  value='Quiz 5'>Quiz 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but this is not quite what i am looking for. This makes every option go to the same quiz.

Comment: that is a better option indeed, but what im trying to do is what The Humble Rat mentioned in the first comment. Im trying to figure out if there is a php code that will add new quizes when they are created to the select option as well as allow selecting them

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use html tags inside php ,add an

eg:

```
 echo"<select>";
```

before every html tag